# Check for existence of parameter in function

Tags: powershell

I have a function as follows:

```
function T
{
    Param
    (
        [switch] $IsValueNameRegularExpression
    )

    ..
}
```

Normally to determine if a parameter exists you would do `if ($Param)`, only seeing as this is a `[switch]`, if the function is called as `T -IsValueNameRegularExpression:$false` will return false on `if ($IsValueNameRegularExpression)`, even though the parameter exists - i.e., the caller specified a value to the optional parameter.

If I change the parameter type from `[switch]` to `[bool]` the same thing will happen, obviously.

In the code for my function I call some .NET methods which contain a default setting for my `[bool]``[switch]` parameters, so unless the user has specified a value (be it true or false) I don't want to pass it to the .NET method.

I could assign default values to the parameter to match those of the default value of the .NET method, but that would be assuming that the default value of the .NET method never changes, which might not be true ...

So, is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use `$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey()` in order to check for a parameter presence:

```
function T
{
    Param
    (
        [switch] $IsValueNameRegularExpression
    )

    $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('IsValueNameRegularExpression')
}

T
T -IsValueNameRegularExpression
T -IsValueNameRegularExpression:$false
```

Output:

```
False
True
True
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Now just need to wait another 5m to mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 3):

An easier (and more accurate way) is to use the IsPresent property.  Using roughly the same code:

```
function T {
    Param (
        [switch] $IsValueNameRegularExpression
    )
    $IsValueNameRegularExpression.IsPresent
}

T
T -IsValueNameRegularExpression
T -IsValueNameRegularExpression:$false
```

yields the following output:

```
False
True
False
```

Note that binding the switch to false makes it "not present"

Comment: This is useless. That's exactly the same as just checking the value of the variable. i.e., `$IsValueNameRegularExpression.IsPresent` returns the same as `$IsValueNameRegularExpression`. This is *not* what I'm after. I was after exactly what Roman said. If you pass `$false`, I want to know that a value was passed, regardless of which value (`$true` or `$false`), your method does no accomplish this...

Answer (score -2):

```
function T 
{
    Param([switch]$IsValueNameRegularExpression)

    $IsValueNameRegularExpression.ToBool()
}
```

Results

```
T
False

T -IsValueNameRegularExpression
True

T -IsValueNameRegularExpression:$true
True

T -IsValueNameRegularExpression:$false
False
```

Comment: This does not answer the question - see comment to Flydog57's answer