# How do I set a variable if a command line parameter is "present" in powershell?

Tags: powershell

If I define the command line parameters as such:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[string[]$myString
)
```

How do I evaluate if `$myString` is present and create a variable to represent yes or no?

Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check for existence of parameter in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326732/check-for-existence-of-parameter-in-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do a null check on the variable:

```
if ($myString) {
 'set true variable' 
} else { 
 'set false variable' 
}
```